# Add items to collapsable menu on xs breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here's my collapsable menu:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"> A </a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"> B </a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"> C </a></li>
     </ul>

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="active"><a href="./"> <i class= 'fa fa-sign-out'></i> Logout </a> </li>
     </ul>  
</div>
```

It has three collapsible items, A, B and C. How could I make it so that when in the mobile breakpoint, the mobile dropdown menu also displays:

```
<li><a href="#contact"> D </a></li>
<li><a href="#contact"> E </a></li>
<li><a href="#contact"> F </a></li>
```

?

I tried doing this:

```
<li class = 'hidden-sm'><a href="#contact"> D </a></li>
```

And it worked, but when I opened the menu in the xs breakpoint and expanded to >= sm, the navbar broke. The mobile nav didn't disappear. It stayed mobile and responsive and broke the layout.

Comment: 'xs' is a starting point... set your rules for 'xs' then override behavior for larger breakpoints